# How do I remove nonnumeric values from my dataset to run the cor.test funciton, I'm a complete novice at R

Tags: r, correlation

Here's the error message:

```
cor.test(executions_correlation$`Age at Execution`,executions_correlation$`Sex of Offender`, method="pearson")
Error in cor.test.default(executions_correlation$`Age at Execution`, executions_correlation$`Sex of Offender`,  : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector
```

I want to know the correlation between these values, but I am stuck in removing nonnumeric values from my dataframe.